# excel show rows having a value in any column

Tags: excel, filter, rows

I have three coulmns

Column1 has values a,e,d
Column2 has values e,a,p 
Filter  has values a,x,y

Now on selecting filter value a in the Filter column the sheet should list two rows i.e. a,e and e.a

please let me know how to do that

Comment: Filters work on a column by column basis. This means if you filter the "Filter" column using the value `a`, it will only show rows in column "Filter" that contain the value `a`.

Answer (score 2):

I also want to filter rows by a value exist in a range of columns.
And I found a way:

- Step1:

  - Add a new column (example: D), and use `COUNTIF` function to check if the value is exist in a range of columns or not.
  - Example: `=COUNTIF($E3:$V3, "Value") > 0`
- Step2:
  Just filter by column D, with the value `TRUE`

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do it using a filter would be with a helper column
In C1, enter =A1&B1 or =CONCATENATE(A1,B1)

THen you can filter C using the text filter. If it contains "a"....

Comment: Cant i make a filter column which can work on both of the columns? Contains will be painful each time for different matching filter criteria.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an Advanced Filter - Data->Advanced

Say on sheet 1 you have:

```
Col1        Col2
e           a
a           x
p           y
```

On Sheet two, write out:

```
Col1        Col2
a
            a
```

(Note that's 3 rows total, 1 for the header, then the first a under col1, then the 2nd a under col2.)

Highlight the range you want to filter on Sheet1, click the Advanced button under the Sort and Filter section of the Data tab on the ribbon - click the Criteria button, navigate to and highlight the criteria you set up on sheet 2, and click Ok

Comment: Yes i am able to do this now but how will i make my sheet 2 to accept dynamic values???